# How to do this in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have a single table called "scores" like this:

```
PLAYER DATE     SCORE
joe    3/1/13   4 
joe    3/3/13   5 
joe    3/6/13   3 
dave   3/3/13   6
dave   3/5/13   8
dave   3/7/13   7
```

How can I query for the LATEST score of each player? To generate a resultset like this:

```
PLAYER  LATEST_SCORE
john    3
dave    7
```

Comment: Please show your work

Comment: My suggestion would be to look at windowing functions like `row_number()` or aggregate functions like `max()`.

Answer (score 2):

The following SQL works under the condition that a given username can only have one entry for a given date.

```
CREATE TABLE #t1 (
    player varchar(max),
    dated datetime,
    score int
)

insert into #t1 values ('joe', '2013-03-01', 4)
insert into #t1 values ('joe', '2013-03-03', 5)
insert into #t1 values ('joe', '2013-03-06', 3)

insert into #t1 values ('dave', '2013-03-03', 6)
insert into #t1 values ('dave', '2013-03-05', 8)
insert into #t1 values ('dave', '2013-03-07', 7)

SELECT  player, score
from    #t1 AS t1
WHERE   dated = (SELECT MAX(t2.DATED) FROM #t1 AS t2 WHERE t1.player = t2.player)

DROP TABLE #t1
```

Comment: very simple solution, excellent!

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT Player, Date, Score
FROM
(
    SELECT Player, Date, Score, Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Player ORDER BY Date DESC)
    FROM Games
) g
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the fields and table in my code with yours.

```
;WITH da_CTE AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY da_player ORDER BY da_date DESC ) AS 'RowNumber',
    da_player,
    da_date,
    da_score
   FROM #s
)

SELECT
    da_player,
    da_score
FROM da_CTE
WHERE RowNumber =1
ORDER BY da_player
```